# How to deny dynamic name generation when creating a checkbox list dynamically

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, attributes

Im creating a checkbox list with **HtmlInputCheckBox** based on some database entries.

Due to validation purposes it's required that all the checkboxes has the same name.

Unfortunately the name attributes are always dynamically generated.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
        foreach (var item in tableItems)
        {
            index += 1;              
            var value = item.GetStringValue("Text", string.Empty);

            var checkbox = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
            checkbox.Name = this.ID;  //<-- This has to be the same for all checkboxes                
            checkbox.Attributes.Add("class", CheckBoxCssClasses);
            checkbox.ID = this.ID + index;
            checkbox.Attributes.Add("value", value);
            if (Required == true)
                checkbox.Attributes.Add("required", "required");
            dynamicCheckboxes.Controls.Add(checkbox);

            var label = new HtmlGenericControl("label");
            label.Attributes.Add("class", LabelCssClasses);
            label.Attributes.Add("for", this.ID + index);
            label.InnerHtml = value;
            dynamicCheckboxes.Controls.Add(label);                
        }
```

Comment: Why dont you assign a static name instead of using the id?

Comment: it doesnt matter - the id ist the asp.control id with client id mode is static. I can also write a string - the result is the same.